WordPress Docker application with PHP-FPM 8.3 based on Alpine Linux not loading contents
I am trying to migrate my WordPress application to Alpine Linux and I used the docker-worpress as my base image instead of the official WordPress as it uses apache.
Here is my modified Dockerfile:
FROM trafex/wordpress:latest

# Copy built files to WordPress file system
COPY default/ /usr/src/wordpress/wp-content/themes/default/
COPY wp-install-plugins.sh /usr/local/bin/

# Update package lists and install MySQL client and net-tools
RUN apk add --no-cache mysql-client net-tools

# Optionally, clean up package cache
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

I am building the app using Jenkins pipeline and providing the docker-compose.yml, wp-config and and wp-install-plugins.sh, as config files which are as below:
docker-compose.yml
version: '3.1'
services:
  wordpress:
    image: myregistry:5000/myapp:current
    container_name: myapp_wordpress_1
    networks:
      - reverse-proxy
    restart: always
    hostname:myapp-dev.mydomain.io
    ports:
      - "8123:80"
    environment:
      DB_HOST: WP_HOST
      DB_USER: WP_DB_USER
      DB_PASSWORD: WP_DB_PWD
      DB_NAME: WPDB_NAME
      VIRTUAL_HOST: myapp-dev.mydomain.io
      FS_METHOD: direct
      WP_DEBUG: "true"
      WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY: "true"
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 80
    volumes:
      - /home/deploy/jenkins/myapp/uploads:/var/www/wp-content/uploads
      - ${WORKSPACE}/uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
      - ${WORKSPACE}/wp-install-plugins.sh:/var/www/wp-install-plugins.sh
      - ${WORKSPACE}/wp-config.php:/var/www/wp-config.php
networks:
  reverse-proxy:
    external:
      name: reverse-proxy

wp-config.php
<?php
define( 'DB_NAME', 'myapp_dev' );
define( 'DB_USER', 'myapp_dev' );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'myapp_password' );
define( 'DB_HOST', 'my_app_db.io:3306' );

define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );

$table_prefix = 'wp_';

define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    define( 'ABSPATH', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' );
}

require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';

wp-install-plugins.sh
#!/bin/bash

wp core download
wp core update --allow-root
wp core update-db --allow-root
wp site list --field=url | xargs -n1 -I % wp --url=% option update timezone_string 'America/New_York' --allow-root
wp plugin delete hello akismet --allow-root
wp site list --field=url | xargs -n1 -I % wp --url=% theme activate default --allow-root
wp theme delete twentysixteen twentyseventeen twentynineteen twentytwenty twentytwentyone twentytwentytwo --allow-root
wp plugin install WP-PGP-Encrypted-Emails contact-form-7 wpcf7-redirect woocommerce wp-recaptcha-integration duplicate-post wordpress-seo wp-content/themes/default/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-pro.zip wp-content/themes/default/plugins/relevanssi-premium.zip timber-library advanced-custom-fields-table-field onelogin-saml-sso --activate --allow-root
wp plugin update --all --allow-root
wp wc update
wp rewrite flush --allow-root


# remove xmlrpc
rm -f /var/www/html/xmlrpc.php

In my application architecture, once the image is built I run the container and then install the plugins by running the wp-install-plugins.sh file in the container, I can install the plugins successfully, but for some reason, the app is not loading and it shows a blank page when I check at the DNS myapp-dev.mydomain.io. I don't see any error logs in the container or the nginx which I am using as reverse proxy when I hit the domain.
When I log into the container and list the files, here is what I see:
docker exec -it myapp_wordpress_1 bash
myapp-dev:/var/www/wp-content# ls -sla
total 248
     4 drwxr-xr-x    6 nobody   nobody        4096 Apr  1 16:06 .
     4 drwxr-xr-x    1 nobody   nobody        4096 Apr  1 16:05 ..
     4 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root           405 Apr  1 16:06 index.php
    20 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root         19915 Apr  1 16:06 license.txt
     8 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root          7399 Apr  1 16:06 readme.html
     4 drwxr-xr-x   12 nobody   nobody        4096 Apr  1 14:00 uploads
     8 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root          7211 Apr  1 16:06 wp-activate.php
     4 drwxr-xr-x    9 root     root          4096 Apr  1 16:06 wp-admin
     4 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root           351 Apr  1 16:06 wp-blog-header.php
     4 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root          2323 Apr  1 16:06 wp-comments-post.php
     4 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root          3013 Apr  1 16:06 wp-config-sample.php
     4 drwxr-xr-x    6 root     root          4096 Apr  1 16:06 wp-content
     8 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root          5638 Apr  1 16:06 wp-cron.php
    16 drwxr-xr-x   27 root     root         16384 Apr  1 16:06 wp-includes
     4 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root          2502 Apr  1 16:06 wp-links-opml.php
     4 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root          3927 Apr  1 16:06 wp-load.php
    52 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root         50927 Apr  1 16:06 wp-login.php
    12 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root          8525 Apr  1 16:06 wp-mail.php
     4 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root           774 Apr  1 16:05 wp-secrets.php
    28 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root         26409 Apr  1 16:06 wp-settings.php
    36 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root         34385 Apr  1 16:06 wp-signup.php
     8 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root          4885 Apr  1 16:06 wp-trackback.php
     4 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root          3154 Apr  1 16:06 xmlrpc.php

Also, I see that my wp-config.php and wp-install-plugins.sh files are copied to the folder /var/www
myapp-dev:/var/www# ls -sla
total 28
     4 drwxr-xr-x    1 nobody   nobody        4096 Apr  1 16:05 .
     8 drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Feb 23 14:06 ..
     4 drwxr-xr-x    1 nobody   nobody        4096 Feb 23 14:06 localhost
     4 -rw-r-----    1 1001     1002           422 Apr  1 16:05 wp-config.php
     4 drwxr-xr-x    6 nobody   nobody        4096 Apr  1 16:06 wp-content
     4 -rw-r-----    1 1001     1002           935 Apr  1 16:05 wp-install-plugins.sh

I am able to corectly establish a connection with the remote DB and I was able to verify that as well, but still the app is not loading. Is there anything else that I am missing out? Is it any issue with permissions? Also, any suggestions to improve these configurations is appreciated.

Did you check your theme? After migrations sometimes the theme selection gets messed up, that causes a blank page display. Just go to Appearance, Themes and make sure a valid theme is selected.
But, I'd recommend using NGINX with an fpm image (fpm is required for NGINX) its going to be cleaner all day. Here's a tutorial.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-docker-compose
